# jQuery DatePicker does not compare years

Tags: jquery, datepicker

It was brought to my attention, using jQuery DatePicker, when comparing dates, the only part of the dates being compared is month and day.

```
$("#complete_date").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,
    onSelect: function(date) {
        if (date < choice_date)
        {
            $("#early_dialog").dialog("open");
            if ($("#alert").length < 1)
            {
                $(".ui-dialog-title").append("<img src='/icon_alert.gif' id='alert'>");
            }
        }

    }
});
```

Basically, the test is if today's date is `8/1/2013` and I choose `1/14/2014`, the `early_dialog` message still appears.

Suggestions?

Comment: make sure that date and choice_date are actual date objects and not strings

Comment: You're not checking if `date` equals `choice_date`, but if `date` is below `choice_date` ?

Comment: Yeah, I want to see if there is a selection earlier than recommended, then there is a popup warning.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$("#datepicker_xxx").datepicker("getDate")` to get the picked date as a Date. Then it's just a matter of

end - begin > `7 * 86400 * 1000`

Comment: I am out, but I will give that a try.  Thanks!